# Transfering ERC20 Tokens from DApp/Smart Contract to user on a Node.js server

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

I have a custom token I've sent to my DApp, and I am trying to send some amount of 'rewards' to my users for posting things on the website. However, it seems like nothing is being sent from my backend server/DApp to the users. I'm wondering what I might be doing wrong here. Code below:

`server.js`

(Basic idea - call `approve` then `transferFrom`)

```
app.post('/send-TOKEN-to-addr', async (req, res) => {

    const post_addr = req.body.addr; // the client sends in user's addr
    var transfer_amt = 5000; // token reward to user
    

    try {
        console.log('send-TOKEN-to-addr gets called for :: '+String(post_addr));
        TOKEN_Contract.methods.approve(DAppAddr, regular_post_transfer_amt).call((err, result) => { 
            console.log('approve:: '+String(result));
            //return res.send(result);
        });
        TOKEN_Contract.methods.transferFrom(DAppAddr, post_addr, transfer_amt).call((err, result) => { 
            //console.log(result);
            return res.send(result);
        });
    
    } catch (e) { throw e; }
});
```

On the backend I get:

`send-TOKEN-to-addr gets called for :: 0xb65ec054bd7f633efd8bd0b59531de464046a7c0`

`approve:: true`

But on the frontend I get no response. As well, when I check the balances of `TOKEN` for the DApp and the `addr`, nothing changes, so I think nothing happens here.

I am seeking advice on getting my DApp to send the tokens it has to other addresses. I confirmed that the DApp has the tokens already, I just can't seem to send on behalf of it within my node.js framework.

### Edit 1

I have some basic functionality already working with my token (within the DApp), such as the below call:

```
app.post('/balanceOf-TOKEN-by-addr', async (req, res) => {

    //console.log('balanceOf-TOKEN-by-addr - server');
    const post_addr = req.body.addr;
    //console.log(post_addr);

    try {
        
        TOKEN_Contract.methods.balanceOf(post_addr).call((err, result) => { 
            //console.log(result);
            return res.send(result);
        });
    
    } catch (e) { throw e; }
});
```

### Edit 2

Adding code for how I initialize my DApp - I will need the private keys to call `send()` methods from it? Because my DApp has a bunch of the `TOKEN`s that I want to send out.

```
const WEB3_PROVIDER = "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545"
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    console.log("web3 already initialized.");
} else {
    // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(WEB3_PROVIDER));
    console.log("New web3 object initialized.");
}

const DAppABIFile = require('./assets/abis/DAppABI'); 
const DAppABI = DAppABIFile.DAppABI;
const DAppAddr = "0x5C7704a050286D742............"; // public key
const DAppContract = new web3.eth.Contract(DAppABI, DAppAddr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between a call (read-only) and a transaction (read-write).

Your snippet only calls the contract but doesn't send transactions. So the contract is not able to write state changes from just the calls.

```
TOKEN_Contract.methods.<method>.call((err, result) => {});
```

---

Web3 uses the `.send()` function ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send)) to send a transaction.

```
TOKEN_Contract.methods.<method>.send({
    from: '0x<sender_address>'
}, (err, result) => {});
```

Note that the transaction needs to be signed with the private key of the `from` address. This can be done in 2 ways:

1. The node provider (most likely passed in the `new Web3(<provider_url>)` constructor) knows the private key to the sender address and has its account unlocked - this is usually done only on local networks used for development.
2. You have passed the sender private key to your web3 instance using the `wallet.add()` function ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add)). Then it gets signed in your JS app, and the payload sent to the node in the background contains only the signed transaction (not the private key).

You can also set this address as the `defaultAccount` ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth.html#defaultaccount)) so that you don't have to keep passing it to the `.send()` function.

Comment: Awesome answer! I think this makes a lot of sense, I totally blanked on needing `send()` rather than `call()`. I do have a question in how you recommend I get the private key of my DApp? I will update the OP question with the code that initializes the DApp on my backend server.

Comment: @JDS Ethereum uses 32byte private keys and derives the address from the private key. There are many ways to generate a private key and corresponding address - including ETH-compatible hardware wallets (e.g. Trezor), standalone SW wallets (e.g. Trust wallet) and browser extensions (e.g. MetaMask). You can also use the web3 method `accounts.create()` ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html#create)) that will generate a new private key and corresponding address. Mind that you need to have ETH funded on the sender address to be able to pay the transaction fees.

Comment: Thanks @Petr for your comment. Are you saying I need to make a new account for my smart contract (DAppAddr) and use said account to distribute tokens, rather than initializing my smart contract (DAppAddr) with the tokens, and trying to distribute from it? That's my confusion; or I thought maybe I can get the private keys for my DAppAddr. Should I do `accounts.create()` with `DAppAddr` then?

Comment: @JDS You can use either of the two approaches. 1) Distribute the tokens from a regular address, or 2) Distribute the tokens from the contract. With the 2nd option you still need a regular address to send a transaction interacting with the contract (as the contract address private key is unknown)... Or there's a third option: You can move the distribution validation and logic to the contract, and let the users interact with the contract on their own (from a frontend app, using a browser-compatible wallet/connector such as MetaMask or WalletConnect), in this case they pay the transaction fees.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I'm very interested in learning how to do the 3rd option - do you have any example code/tutorial I could check out? In either case I'm going to accept your answer :)

Comment: @JDS MetaMask has good examples in their [docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html). Basically you send 2 requests to the API exposed in the `window.ethereum` object - `eth_requestAccounts` to get the user address, and `eth_sendTransaction` to send the transaction (you need the user's address as the `from` field value). In both cases, the MetaMask wallet pops up in the browser and the user needs to confirm the action (to give you their address, and then to send the tx)... I don't have any experience with WalletConnect, but I'm guessing the flow is going to be similar.

Answer (score 2):

Well first check if the wallet that you are using to call the functions is the owner of the tokens and not the dapp, if the dapp is the owner i would recommend you that the address you are using to call the contract have an owner permission and add the dapp contract a function to send the token to some address, if the address that you are using is the owner of the tokens just call the ´TOKEN_CONTRACT.methods.transfer(post_addr,transfer_amt)´

now, just as an explanation, the reason because that endpoint is not sending the tokens is this, in that operation are 4 address used, the user address, the contract address, the token address and the address you are using to send the transactions from the backend, when you call `TOKEN_Contract.methods.approve(DAppAddr, regular_post_transfer_amt)` you are approving the contract address to move the tokens that owns the address you use in your backend not viceversa, for that the contract would have made that call and pass as a parameter the backend address, so when you call `TOKEN_Contract.methods.transferFrom(DAppAddr, post_addr, transfer_amt)` you are trying to move the tokens of the contract approved to the backend address and send it to the user address, but the amount of this approved tokens is 0, because the thing i explained before